# How to know that user don't give internet access to our app?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, permissions, admob

Android system now gives users the decision to give or restrict internet access to selected apps. This is very detrimental to developers, especially for developers that use AdMob and other advertisement services. How to know that users don't give internet access to our app so i can give them warnings?

This is what i mean "Android system now gives users the decision to give or restrict internet access to selected apps":
[image]

Comment: Im not aware that users should confirm INTERNET. What do you mean? Which Android system?

Comment: @blackapps this is what i mean: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gfmc7.jpg

Comment: What do you mean? I see no internet mentioned. Where are you talking about?

Answer (score 1):

Internet permission is normal permission in android 12(Which is least preview version of android) too. I don't know what is your problem but if you want to check user's network status, see this document https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/managing

**EDIT**

In your case, if turning off switch, android will block network in background. This document will help you https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/data-saver?hl=en

Forground access will works fine. You're able to access internet switch has been disabled also.

Comment: Thanks, i will try it. I hope the codes work 